# Keras optimizing two outputs with a custom loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I've been recently trying to implement a model, which can be described as following: Given an input matrix and a set of targets, let the model learn, simultaneously, the matrix representation, as well as the targets via a custom loss function.

The architecture (simplified):

```python
input_matrix = Input(shape=(i_shape,))
layer1 = Dense(100)(input_matrix)
output = Dense(3)(layer1)

autoencoder_mid = Dense(100)(input_matrix)
autoencoder_output = Dense(i_shape)(autoencoder_mid)
```

My idea of a loss function:

```python
def customLoss(true_matrix,pred_matrix):
    def combined_loss(y_true,y_pred):
        return K.abs(y_true-y_pred)
        a = K.mean( K.square(y_pred - y_true) * K.exp(-K.log(1.7) * (K.log(1. + K.exp((y_true - 3)/5 )))),axis=-1  )
        b = K.mean( K.square(pred_matrix - true_matrix) * K.exp(-K.log(1.7) * (K.log(1. + K.exp((true_matrix - 3)/5 )))),axis=-1)
        return a+b
    return combined_loss
```

I compile the model as:

```python
net = Model(input_matrix, [output,autoencoder_output])
net = net.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=customLoss(true_matrix=X,pred_matrix=autoencoder_output))
```

Where I try to fit the network with a standard:

```python
 net.fit(X,
         target,
         epochs=10,
         batch_size=10)
```

The error I get is:

```python
ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float32 for Tensor with dtype float64: 'Tensor("loss/dense_4_loss/Log_3:0", shape=(389, 3890), dtype=float64, device=/device:GPU:0)'
```

My question is, is there any other way of doing this? If so, could you please point me towards a possible solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```python
def customLoss(true_matrix):
    def combined_loss(y_true,y_pred):
        y_pred, pred_matrix = y_pred
        ...
    return combined_loss

net = Model(input_matrix, [output,autoencoder_output])
net.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=customLoss(X))
```

As the original y_pred will be a touple with `(output,autoencoder_output)`.

Concerning the double `return`, the function will only return the first one, so I'd remove one of the two return lines or combine the two outputs such as:

```python
alpha = 0.5
beta = 0.5
...
loss1, loss2 = K.abs(y_true-y_pred), a+b

return alpha*loss1 + beta*loss2
```

Changing `alpha` and `beta` upon convenience.

Thus, the whole thing could be:

```python
def customLoss(true_matrix, alpha = 0.5, beta = 0.5):
    def combined_loss(y_true,y_pred):
        y_pred, pred_matrix = y_pred
        a = K.mean( K.square(y_pred - y_true) * K.exp(-K.log(1.7) * (K.log(1. + K.exp((y_true - 3)/5 )))),axis=-1  )
        b = K.mean( K.square(pred_matrix - true_matrix) * K.exp(-K.log(1.7) * (K.log(1. + K.exp((true_matrix - 3)/5 )))),axis=-1)
        loss1, loss2 = K.abs(y_true-y_pred), a+b
        return alpha*loss1 + beta*loss2 
    return combined_loss

net = Model(input_matrix, [output,autoencoder_output])
net.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=customLoss(X))
```

Comment: Nice, no problem!

Comment: One follow up question, sorry. Could I potentially use input_matrix instead of X in the loss=customLoss(X) method?

Comment: In that case it might be easier to put it in the outputs as well, i.e. `net = Model(input_matrix, [output,autoencoder_output,input_matrix])` and then inside the function: `y_pred, pred_matrix, input_matrix = y_pred`, although this way you will get the input_matrix for the particular batch being processed.

Comment: How can this work? At least in Keas 2.2.4 when I supply one loss function it gets applied to each output separately and y_pred is a Tensor not tuple. Moreover I'm afraid that X is a numpy array not a Tensor.